# How do I search the comments of Hinduism.SE?

Tags: support, status-completed, sources-and-citations

As it says in the title, how do I search through comments of Hinduism.SE or meta.Hinduism.SE?

E.g., I'm interested in finding out all answers that lacked references or citations of a credible source to support the answer. So I want to search for "cite sources" (and leave another reminder there ;-)

But when I search for "cite sources" in the main search field at the top-right, I only get a handful of results. These results are not really the comments I was looking for but questions containing those words and it doesn't solve my problem.

Another and more useful use case is you often remember reading a helpful comment somewhere under a question or answer and a few days later you want to go back to it but can't recollect where exactly you saw it .

Comment: How is it a [tag:feature-request]

Comment: @AnkitSharma The question is about a feature lacking on the main site or something SE doesn't inherently support. I posted a similar question [here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/451/2995), also a feature request. I think you meant to link to this [feature-request](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: i got that one but for this one you already suggested a way using data explorer query and even accepted the answer. So looked like a closer to me. So just wanted to clear.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes, this issue is closed (or feature request is complete) and can be marked status-completed if that's what you meant to ask. (FYI, only mods can mark status-completed, else I would have already done it so :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, it's real easy using the following **search-comments** query of [StackExchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)<sup>**</sup>.

[http://data.stackexchange.com/**hinduism**/query/114513/search-comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/114513/search-comments)

Just type the search term<sup>++</sup> in the parameters field and hit Run Query.

(For quick reference, direct link to results of "cite sources" is [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/114513/search-comments?SearchQuery=cite%20sources).)

[image]

<sup>++</sup>search term is case sensitive.

<sup>**</sup>DISCLAIMER:

> #### How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?
>
> The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was Jan 24 at 6:30. [Today is Jan 29, 2016]

Comment: Thanks, I'd never heard of this before.  Another tool I find useful is the one that generates a list of the most recent comments that have been posted on the site.  I use it so often that I've created a shortlink for it: http://tinyurl.com/hcomments

Comment: (I added a disclaimer) Nice. How do you use the data from the API? You have it e-mailed to you everyday? Is it up-to-date unlike the data explorer?

Comment: Yeah, the API accesses data in real time, so even comments that were just posted immediately show up.  There's probably a way to search the comments using the API rather than the Data explorer, but I'm not a programming person so I'm not sure how.  I don't do anything fancy like have the data emailed to me, I just load the url every so often and see the latest comments.  I do it both for moderation purposes, like finding out about questions or answers that need my attention, or just personal purposes like seeing interesting comments I might want to respond to.